# How to return single value using ExecuteScalarAsync on a dbcommand using system.data.common on C# blazor wasm

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, blazor

I have a method on a controller that is a validation check for another component on the front end. The parameter I am passing through is a int called panelId and the return value is either 0 or 1. It seems I cannot cast the object from executescalarasync to a int directly. Any ideas?

```
  public async Task<bool> CheckIfNewPanelIsValid(int? panelId)
        {
            int IsValid = 0;

            using var dbConnection = await _dbConnectionFactory.CreateAcutisConnectionAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            using var dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateDbCommand();
            
            try
            {
                //Product Line List Store procedure
                dbCommand.CommandText = "sp_GET_PRODUCT_PANEL_STATUS";
                dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                dbCommand.AddParameter("@panelid", panelId);

                var retval = dbCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync();
                IsValid = Convert.ToInt32(retval);
              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                dbCommand.Dispose();
                dbConnection.Close();
            }

           if(IsValid == 1)            
                return true;       
           else
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you din't `await` it, you have a `Task<object?>` instead of an `object?`.

Change it to:

```
var retval = await dbCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync();
```